# C# Check if an List<enum> item is selected in a listbox and if so return true

Tags: c#, wpf, lambda, listbox

I am trying to validate if an Item which is part of an Enum list is selected in a checkbox.

I am trying something like this:

```
if (CrystalsHeldBox2.SelectedItem == Player.CrystalsHeld.Find(item => item == Player.Crystals.Ayanlune))
```

It is part of a class as follows:

```
[JsonProperty("CrystalsHeld")]
public List<Crystals> CrystalsHeld { get; set; }

[JsonProperty("RV")]
public List<string> RV { get; set; }

public Player()
{
    Inventory = new List<Item>();
    CrystalsHeld = new List<Crystals>();
    RV = new List<string>();
}

public enum Crystals : int
{
    Ayanlune = 1
}
```

Basically I want to do something like this:
If Ayanlune Crystal is in the Listbox that displays all of the player CrystalsHeld, be true.

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: The last statement of the question is confusing. Can you explain what exactly you are trying to do here? And what issue you are facing with this code ?

Comment: What framework are you using?  Winforms?  WPF? Asp.Net MVC?

Comment: I am using the WPF framework.

Comment: @ChetanRanpariya I am trying to check if the selected item match the Ayanlune enum from the Player.Crystals. The list is made of all the Player.Crystals that has been stored in the CrystalHeld attribute.

Comment: And what issue you are facing with this code ;

Comment: if (CrystalsHeldBox2.SelectedItem == Player.CrystalsHeld.Find(item => item == Player.Crystals.Ayanlune)) does not seem to work, it returns Operator == cannot be applied to operands of type 'object' and 'Player.Crystals'

Comment: What is the type in CrystalsHeldBox2? Crystals ?

Comment: ListBox CrystalsHeldBox2 = new ListBox();
CrystalsHeldBox2.ItemsSource = Player.CrystalsHeld;

Answer (score 0):

I don't think you need LINQ for this. A simple [`List<T>.Contains`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bhkz42b3(v=vs.110).aspx) should do:

```
if (Player.CrystalsHeld.Contains((Crystals) CrystalsHeldBox2.SelectedItem))
```

Comment: Cannot convert from 'object' to 'Game.Player.Crystals'

Comment: But this wouldn't work for me. I want to use this like a switch. Meaning there might be many different Crystals that are contained in it. I need to check if that specific crystal is selected.
In sum, I'm listing all of the crystals the player have in the box, then the player can select the one they want and press a button and that button checks which one was selected and return true for that one.

Comment: You're right, I added the cast. As for your second comment - isn't that exactly what this code does? You choose a specific crystal type that you're currently interested in (`CrystalsHeldBox2.SelectedItem`), and you want to see whether that crystal is in the player's list (`Contains`).

Comment: I think I had badly explained, my apologies. I have a list and I select an item in the list. I want to see if that item match a specific one. I've figured it out. `if (CrystalsHeldBox2.SelectedItem.Equals(Player.Crystals.Ayanlune))` but thanks for the information on cast, I didn't know I could do that.

Answer (score 0):

`CrystalsHeld` is a `List`, not a `ListBox`.  A `ListBox` is a UI control, while a `List` is a C# collection.

You can check if a `List` contains an object like this:

```
if (CrystalsHeld.Contains(CrystalsHeldBox2.SelectedItem))
{
    // Do Stuff
}
```

If it is actually a `ListBox`, then that control has an `Items` property that contains what is in the `ListBox`.  You can get to it in code behind like:

```
if (CrystalsHeld.Items.Contains(CrystalsHeldBox2.SelectedItem))
{
    // Do Stuff
}
```

Or if you are using MVVM, you can bind the control's `Items` property to a property in your ViewModel and so something similar.

Comment: I have a listbox uielement that has the elements contained in CrystalHeld List<Crystals> being displayed. I want to check if the one being selected matches a specific one.

Answer (score 0):

So! I figured it out! I needed to do Equals:

```
if (CrystalsHeldBox2.SelectedItem.Equals(Player.Crystals.Ayanlune))
                {
                    AddInline("This is the right object!");
                }
```